# How can I "create" different paths in an url for a website and for each path call a different "status"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a programme in javascript which you can use to draw, with canvas. Now I created a webserver with nodejs and try to implement, that you can draw something on this website and for this particular picture, the URL makes an extra path which you can call and you get to the picture at the same point where you stopped last time drawing.
Here is the code:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.method, request.url);
    console.log("  ", request.url.substring(1));
    if (request.url === '/') request.url = '/draw.html';
    fs.readFile(request.url.substring(1), function (err, data) {
        console.log("Datei lesen", err);
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        if (err) {
            response.write("Kann nicht geladen werden: "+request.url);
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(8081);
```

This is only giving one "page". I'm looking for something like http://127.0.0.1:8081/image123/draw.html → and you get to picture with ID 123. Ans so for each picture you create a different path, so you can visit each picture.

Maybe something like this:

```
if (url.includes('bild') && /[0-9]/.test(url)) {
    request.url = ???;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why shouldn't you write your app in ReactJS or Angular. It is more easier.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that is.

Answer (score 1):

You need a middleware like Express JS for this. In Express JS, you can use parameterised queries:

```
const express = require("express");
app = express();

app.get("/:image/draw.html", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.image); // image123
  // So, if you need that 123, then you can do:
  console.log(parseInt(req.params.image.replace("image", ""), 10)); // 123
});
```

The reason for `replace()` function above is it only replaces once:

```
» "image123image".replace("image", "");
« "123image"
```

Comment: @DanielReimer What?

Comment: I did not understand how the new path is leading to a new "page". I know how to query the url, but how can I save the image243 behind the url /image243/draw.html? Because when I use this url I get to a blank site, without any content.

Comment: @DanielReimer Inside the `.get()` function, you need to do something like `res.send("./draw.html")` - something like that. `:)` I thought you would be able to figure out looking at the documentation [`app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method).

Comment: @DanielReimer Let me know if you need me... `:)`